# UIApplication sharedApplication tel: add numbers to the current call (objective-c)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, telephony

With iPhone you can dial a number and you can add some other persons to the call using the iPhone-panel (manually).

I want to do it automatically.

I can dial a number from my native iPhone-Application with:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:...."]
```

The native "call" get started and when I finish it, I get back to my application. But I can dial from my application only one number.

Is there a possibility to send other numbers/to add other contacts to the call (during the call or at the beginning)?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 6):

No, this not presently possible. First of all, your application can't do anything during a call, since it cannot run in the background. Second, Apple has, understandably, kept access to the phone pretty restricted and therefore has not provided API to do this.